# jquery slideshow onclick next slide

Tags: jquery, wordpress, onclick, slideshow

I am new to jquery and am having a lot of trouble customising my Wordpress 'Easy Gallery Slider' plugin.

**Here is the website:** http://andycallahan.eu/2012/bikes-2/

I would like the slideshow to advance to the next slide when the image is clicked.

The reason I am having so much trouble is that the image inside the slideshow is not in it's own div, so it would have to be a ul/li onclick event.

I am not quite sure what code snippets to show, so to conserve space here are the links:

**jquery.flexslider.js:** http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0G8K

Thanks so much!

Comment: I can only post two URLs, so here are some more code snippets that could be useful.

**flexslider.css:** http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0G8L

**jquery.flexslider-min.js:** http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0G8M

Answer (score 0):

The docs say, that there's a slider.flexAnimate(target) method.
Use it in `$("ul.slides img").click(function(ev){ /* here */ }).`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm sorry but I am very new to this so could you please elaborate.


I am currently looking in **jquery.flexslider.js**. Where should I place


`$("ul.slides img").click(function(ev){ /* here */ }).`?


Am I right in assuming that `{ /* here */ })` is where I would include the onclick event?


Thank you.

Comment: The code should live on the same page, where you are using the jquery.flexslider.js and make sure to wrap the onclick handling code in $(document).ready(function(){ /* here */});